# If a Topological Space contains a Point whose Open Neighborhood System that forms an Open Cover, is the Space necc. Hyper connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $C$ be an Open Cover of an arbitrary Topological Space $(X,T_{X})$ i.e $C\subseteq{T_{X}}$ and $\cup {U}$ where $C=\Cup { U}\in{T_{X}}$ equals $X$.

Suppose $\exists x\in{X}:N_{x}$ is an Open of Cover of $X$ where $N_{x}$ is the Open Neighborhood of $x$, i.e all Open Sets of $X$ containing $x$.

I believe that if $X$ contains such a Point, that $X$ is necessarily Hyperconnected, here is my argument:

1.)
If $N_{x}$ is indeed an Open Cover of $X$, and since $X = \cup{N_{x}}$, then $(\forall{y\in{X}})y\in{N_X}$.

2.) $(y\in{N_{x}})\implies{N_{y}}\cap{N_{x}}\neq{\emptyset}$.

Thus if a Space $X$ contains such a Point ${x}$ then it is necessary that $X$ is a Hyperconnected Space.

Is this true or am I missing something? Proofs would be appreciated.

Comment: $N_x$ always contains $X$, thus $N_x$ is always an open cover of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Frost has answered my question within his comment:

> $N_{x}$ always contains $X$, thus $N_{x}$ is always an open cover of $X .-$ Paul Frost 3 hours ago